# How can/should I limit the amount of HTTP requests within a given period of time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, request, limit

In order to avoid unwonted data storage I would like to limit the amount of HTTP requests that my server would accept in a given period of time, for example up to once per ten seconds. Practically speaking, I would like to make a my controller action to respond with an error message if there are too many HTTP requests per period. How can/should I do that? Should it be handled in middleware?

---

**UPDATE**

I am looking for a way to make a controller action to run for an incoming HTTP request. Then, within the controller action code, I would like to check if the last resource object has been accessed (through a HTTP request) in the last 10 seconds, and I would like to make that *comparing the time when the last HTTP request has been performed with the "log-time" that it is stored in the database for that resource object*.

The "log-time" is an attribute related to the mentioned resource object (a Ruby on Rails ActiveModel object) and it is intended to store the last time at which that object is accessed (through a HTTP request). So, if for that resource object have been performed too many HTTP requests per period then I would like to generate an error.

Answer (score 2):

This might be better handled by Nginx or Apache. Not every HTTP requests goes through your Rails application. For example, requests for static assets are often handled by Nginx/Apache directly. Moreover, as you scale your application, you might eventually have multiple Rails processes behind the same nginx server.

For nginx, the [HttpLimitReqModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLimitReqModule) might be what you need. When the limit is exceeded, the server will respond with `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable`. A [custom error page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-nginx-customizing-404-403-error-page/) can be created for this status code.

For apache, there is [mod_ratelimit](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_ratelimit.html) and [mod_evasive](https://coderwall.com/p/eouy3g).

(This might be obvious, but an additional advantage of handling rate limits in nginx/apache is that requests over the limit don't even go into your Rails processes. Nginx/Apache will cut them off immediately, potentially saving some CPU.)

Comment: Anyway, I am looking for a way to make a controller action to run for an incoming HTTP request. Then, within the controller action code, I would like to check if the last *resource object* access (an HTTP request) has been performed in the last 10 seconds, and I would like to make that comparing the time when the last HTTP request has been performed with the "log-time" that it is stored in the database for that *resource object*. If so, raise an error.

Comment: @Backo Why do you insist in doing it that way?

Comment: Because I would like to use a "log-time" attribute related to the previously mentioned *resource object* (a Ruby on Rails `ActiveModel` object), which attribute is intended to store the last time at which that object is accessed (through a HTTP request). So, if for that object have been performed too many HTTP requests per period then I would like to generate an error.

Comment: Using [before_filter](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) might work, but I doubt rate limiting will improve performance if every request, even rejected ones, writes to the DB.

Comment: @Jim Lim - How can/should I implement the `before_filter`?
*Note*: Not all HTTP requests writes to the database. It depends on if HTTP requests per period are or not are too many.